# Magento 2 - How to suspend customer by admin or them self?

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend, backend

In Magento 2, How to suspend customer by admin or them self ?, I need solution and how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Suspend Customer means? U can disable/delete it right?

Answer (score 0):

From Admin you can delete customers, but that's permanent. I don't believe disabling customers is a standard functionality. There's no button or switch for it anywhere in Customers configuration.

So I suggest you develop a custom module that adds an attribute `enabled` to Customer, with an Observer that intercepts any `isLoggedIn` calls and checks your attribute and returns false if customer is disabled. And of course a field for the attribute in Edit Customer.